# How to replace properly the motherboard and CPU on a Windows 7 machine?

Tags: windows-7, cpu, motherboard

I am going to replace the motherboard, CPU, and RAM of my Windows 7 PC (at home, this is not a server, of course). What is the proper way - relative to the software and not to the hardware, unless of course it is relevant for some reason! - to proceed in doing so? Will there be problems that could require an OS reinstall?

Will an image of the system taken with the old hardware be useful with the new one? Since the make of the motherboard and the CPU is the same (in my case, respectively, Asus and Intel), can I update the drivers before swapping the hardware?

Is Sysprep useful/required for the smoothness of the process?

**UPDATE**

I did it. In the process I have lost my floppy drive, since the new MB doesn't provide a suitable connector any longer. I had never used the old one, still it makes me feel old.

The only issue that I have faced was that I tried to set up the hard disks as AHCI without having done the homework (that is, without having checked if it was supposed to work). It didn't, so I reverted to IDE and all was fine.

The only clarification to the answers that I received which is worthwhile to add is that it's not easy at all to download the drivers from the web (or I didn't find it: there is not a "single package" but a whole lot of files to be downloaded one by one). But, luckily, **it was not needed**: they were provided on a dvd. So at least in my case, *it simply worked*.

Comment: I have looked around and found some similar questions, but not duplicate (to my comprehension). In particular, I am looking for "how to do it and do it well" while many questions and answers focus on the "is it possible" and the answer in this case appears to be "yes, with newer OS". If I missed some relevant duplicate, please point them out! :)

Comment: `I am going to replace the motherboard, cpu and ram of my windows 7 pc (at home, this is not a server, of course). What is the proper way to proceed in doing so?`   That’s a little vague, are you asking about physically installing it?

Comment: The first thing to do is to make sure you have backups. Even if you are probably not going to need them. E.g. use clonezilla/ghost/acronis$whatever) to create a full disk image. Now sysprep the OS removing all old drivers and shut down (do not reboot or the drivers which sysprep removed will be reinstalled). Change the hardware. Boot. The OS will now start cleanly, without old drivers on the new hardware.

Comment: @synetech: I am going to physically replace the MB (and the cpu and ram installed on it). If you think that I can phrase it clearer, please suggest an edit. I hope that this question may become a reference on how to properly proceed in these cases.

Comment: @Francesco, yes, but are you looking for help with the physical process or just the software aspect?

Comment: @Hennes thanks. My main concern is with pics, which I routinely archive. All the rest is replaceable, but is backupped just in case :)

Comment: Synetech: ok I see the point of your question. My concern is relative to software (for the hardware, I would go to serverfault.com I guess :-) )

Comment: @Francesco, actually hardware would be here too (SF is for professional admin questions). But you hadn’t clarified if you need help with the hardware installation or not because the question focuses on software. If you have any questions about physically installing it, then go ahead and edit the question to specify what the obstacle is (though it’s *usually* fairly straightforward; the plugs all go in only one way and such—just don’t forget to plug everything like power-cords and such in).

Comment: @synetech thanks, I tried to clarify, do you feel it's ok now?

Comment: @Francesco, So... did you have any problems or not?

Comment: @JoshCampbell I added an update, isn't it clear enough ? (I fear that my writing skills are not so good, then :-) ). No, all in all I didn't have any problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am going to replace the motherboard, cpu and ram of my windows 7 pc (at home, this is not a server, of course). Am I expected to incur issues which could require to re-install the OS?

No, you *shouldn’t* have to re-install Windows, but there are a couple of things you will need to be ready for:

- You will need to install new drivers for the different hardware.

  When Windows was installed, it installed the drivers for the old hardware, so now you’ll need to install the appropriate drivers. The CPU and RAM won’t be a problem, but the motherboard contains numerous components, each requiring drivers (chipset, audio, video, network, drive controllers, etc.) Worse, without the appropriate drivers, Windows may not be able to boot enough to even prompt you to install the new drivers.

  What you’ll want to do is to boot into safe-mode the first time after installing the hardware, then install the drivers there (your specific hardware may have different instructions, but this is typical for a new motherboard on an existing Windows installation).

  Once Windows has the basic drivers ready, you can usually install other drivers in normal mode (again, your hardware’s drivers should tell you what’s required).

  Just make sure that you have all of the required drivers ready and on hand (download them *before* installing the new hardware).
- Windows may require you to re-[activate](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/activate-windows-7-on-this-computer). Again, this *shouldn’t* be a problem; you should be able to re-activate online, but if your Internet connection isn’t working (e.g., you haven’t installed the motherboard’s NIC drivers yet), you should be able to activate via a phone-call.

> Will an image of the system taken with the old HW be useful with the new one?

It can be useful in case you want to put the old hardware in. Like I said, you’ll have to install new drivers for the new hardware, so Windows will be in a somewhat different state afterwards. If you have the space, then taking a backup is a good idea in case there’s a problem like the hardware is defective and you need to put the old one back in while waiting for a replacement.

> Since the make of the motherboard and the cpu is the same (in my case, respectively, asus and intel)

The make of the components don’t matter, the models do. Unless you are replacing the motherboard and CPU with identical model numbers, it will require new drivers (and even then, it might still need new drivers due to different revisions, etc.)

> can I update the drivers before swapping the hardware?

No, you can’t install drivers for different hardware and even if you could, your old hardware would stop working; you need those to remain installed until you shut down. (Technically, you *can* “install” the drivers in advance, by which I mean putting the files on the system so that Windows can find them when it needs to, but that depends on your hardware’s driver installers; some won’t proceed if they don’t detect the hardware, other let you install regardless.)

> Is Sysprep useful/required for the smoothness of the process?

You can “slipstream” drivers into a Windows installation disk, but you have already installed it. SysPrep is generally for *cloning* a system like putting the same exact installation onto dozens of identical systems. This isn’t really your situation, so it’s not of much use here.

For your situation, your best bet is to download the drivers, unpack them, and have them ready in a location that will be available to Windows when it tries to install them. This means that they cannot be on a drive that requires special drivers for Windows to be able to access them (e.g., RAID); consider putting them on a flash-drive or erasable CD/DVD in that case.

Comment: Synetech, thanks for the answer. I think that it could be very useful if you could explain where do one looks for the drivers before replacing the HW (I guess, and @jdh confirms it, that you mean from the website of the MB, in my case ASUS).

Comment: @Synetech, no offense, but how long has it been since you last put a computer together? "Worse, without the appropriate drivers, Windows may not be able to boot enough to even prompt you to install the new drivers" since when? "•Windows may require you to re-activate. Again, this shouldn’t be a problem" Umm... no it won't.

Comment: Yes, you’ll want to get the drivers from the Asus website. Look for the page for that specific model and look in the *Downloads* tab. (They may also have a program that can detect and install drivers.)

Comment: @JoshCampbell, if Windows doesn’t have built-in drivers for the new hardware, then parts of the motherboard could run in basic mode if at all, especially if it can’t access Windows Update. (Or are you saying that Windows can boot up with any and all hardware in the world, including brand-spanking-new stuff that came out after Windows?)

Comment: @Synetech, I suppose anything is possible, but in 11 years of building high-end computers I have never encountered any issues like those mentioned. At worse case, he will need to re-instal his network drivers, but I highly doubt it. Once he swaps his hardware and connects his old drive Windows 7 will fire. I'd bet $2.31 on it. Mostly cash.

Comment: @JoshCampbell 2.31 is not reassuring enough, do you think you could raise that to 2.50 at least, bank guaranteed? :-)

Comment: `I suppose anything is possible, but in 11 years of building high-end computers I have never encountered any issues like those mentioned.`   Only 11? I guess that’s why you have such (mostly unfounded) confidence in Windows’ ability to handle new, even cutting-edge hardware.   `At worse case, he will need to re-instal his network drivers, but I highly doubt it. Once he swaps his hardware and connects his old drive Windows 7 will fire.`   You’ve obviously never had to press `F6` when installing Windows; consider yourself lucky.

Comment: @Synetech - Can't he place Windows into a stage where it removes all the hardware drivers and goes into a mode where in the next reboot drivers are reinstalled?

Comment: @Ramhound, `Can't he place Windows into a stage where it removes all the hardware drivers`   *Is there* a stage that makes Windows remove drives? And do they really want to remove *all* drivers?   `goes into a mode where in the next reboot drivers are reinstalled?`   It does this anyway when it detects new hardware, you don’t *have* to remove the old drivers (in show-hidden-devices mode, my Device Manager shows countless pieces of old, no-longer-present hardare).

Comment: @Ramhoundm, also,  Windows would still have to get the drivers from *somewhere*. This isn’t a problem if you are installing something that doesn’t affect Windows’ ability to boot and access the Internet (assuming that Windows Update has appropriate drivers). But the motherboard is a critical piece of equipment and it could potentially prevent Windows from booting or accessing drives or the Internet.

Comment: @Synetech - The mode I describe, saw somebody explain how to enable, is how Acronis True Image can migrate a Windows installation to entirely new hardware.

Comment: -1 Sysprep is NOT generally for cloning.  Sysprep is for EXACTLY what he wants to do, which is to strip away hardware specific drivers and return the installation to an Out-Of-Box-Experience, so that it can boot properly once it is being run on a new motherboard.  Would you care for a tutorial?  http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/135077-windows-7-installation-transfer-new-computer.html

Comment: @BonGart, `Sysprep is NOT generally for cloning.`   [Yes it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysprep) [absolutely *is*](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302577). The whole point to SysPrep was to simplify deployment for organizations with numerous systems.   `Sysprep is for EXACTLY what he wants to do, which is to strip away hardware specific drivers … so that it can boot properly once it is being run on a new motherboard. Would you care for a tutorial? http… `   Wrong. Just because it can help with that doesn’t make that its original/only purpose.

Comment: @BonGart, besides, you don’t *necessarily have* to remove drivers anyway. Even if they take your advice and use SysPrep to remove the drivers, that doesn’t help them get the new drivers installed and working. Either Windows will be able to handle the new hardware enough to get the new drivers installed (in which case they likely didn’t need to bother going to the effort of removing the old ones—this isn’t a video card we’re talking about), or it won’t work without manual intervention even with SysPrep.

Comment: No, it is not.  If you **choose** to take the prepped installation and clone it, you most certainly can.  What it **does** is strip away the drivers to prepare for a change of hardware.  It is just a tool.  Stripping away the drivers in prep for cloning to different hardware is great, but if it was a cloning tool, then it would clone.  And just exactly what advice did I give?  I think you are jumping to conclusions and getting a bit defensive.  I most certainly did **not** provide an answer for the question, or give the OP advice on how to do anything.  Only gave YOU a link on using Sysprep.

Comment: @BonGart, you have it backwards. SysPrep was designed specifically to deploy a Windows installation to multiple systems. Like you said, it is only a tool and at a base level, it just flags Windows to notice the first time it boots on other systems that it needs to update hardware serials numbers, generate new SIDs, etc. so that they are not identical and don’t create conflicts. Part of that includes signalling to Windows to check for different hardware, but that happens anyway when Windows boots up; SysPrep just lets you provide them in advance (which I already said is doable).

Comment: Maybe you misinterpreted what I wrote and thought I was saying SysPrep is a *disk*-cloning tool. I *never* said that; I clearly said it was for cloning a *system*. SysPrep is a part of that; I could have gone into detail about deployment, but that would be irrelevant here because it does not apply, so I kept it simple.     And I am not jumping to conclusions (though you might be), nor am I being defensive. I grew tired of your hostile, aggressive attitude a long time ago. Instead of editing or commenting, you down-vote an entire answer because you (mistakenly) disagree with a single sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Making an image of your drive is very important if it contains anything not backed up. There is always a remote chance (Murphy's law) that something might happen in the transfer that would cause the drive to become unbootable on both old and new motherboards (although I think this is unlikely).

When the HD boots up on the new motherboard, windows 7 will detect and load the new drivers. It can use generic drivers for most devices. Typically the network driver would be one that requires a specific install, and if possible should be pre-loaded. Otherwise you'll have to download it on another machine and transfer it via USB stick.
You should also research and install the AHCI hard drive driver. This is a bios option for IDE or AHCI driver interfaces.

Lastly, some software might detect the new HW configuration and require you to re-validate it's license. So have those licenses on hand.

If this is the only machine you have available, you should download all drivers from the motherboard support site and have them available on a USB stick.

Answer (score 1):

If the case has a slide out motherboard tray take it out and insert the riser screws, mount the board and insert the CPU & RAM. Else, set the motherboard on the foam antistatic pad it came with (usually black or red), instal the CPU & RAM, insert riser screws into case and attatch the board. DO NOT FORGET THE RISER SCREWS. You will damage the board if you do.

If you're just replacing everything and not building a new system, then you should have no need for an image. Just instal your old hard drive and your existing Windows 7 OS will automatically detect drivers for your new hardware. If everything is exactly like your old hardware (which I doubt, unless you bought doubles of everything at the same time), then your old drivers will work on your swapped out hardware.

**UPDATE 09-2019:** This answer is no longer valid for current gen hardware. Nearly all of today's hardware is designed/packaged specifically for Windows 8.x and Windows 10.x Operating Systems. Most hardware installation CDs no longer include legacy drivers, and because Windows 7/Vista are no longer supported, no modern hardware drivers through Windows Updates. If you do decide to upgrade that old PC with some fancy new tech, and you're 100% firm on sticking with Windows 7 (like me) then you will most likely need to download special legacy drivers from the manufacturer website.

Comment: I am changing MB, cpu and ram. All the rest is the same (minus the usb 3 card which I won't need any longer, since this new MB is already usb 3 compliant). Thanks for the remainder about the riser screw. So the answer is: there's nothing to do? Sysprep is not needed?

Comment: No, it's not needed.

Comment: `If everything is exactly like your old hardware`   It’s not; they are putting a different motherboard in.     `your existing Windows 7 OS will automatically detect drivers for your new hardware.`   And where does it get them? Windows Update? That presumes that Windows can access the Internet which is not guaranteed when changing a fundamental component like the motherboard (assuming of course that Windows boots at all and doesn’t get tripped up on some fancy new stuff that it doesn’t support out of the box—remember `F6`?).

Comment: @Synetech, haha... you should have waited for my other answer before posting this. Plus, I already mentioned that I doubt his hardware is the same. Touche

Comment: Although my answers were technically correct back in 2013, they are no longer valid today. Windows 7/Vista are no longer supported with modern hardware. Follow the instructions @Synetech provided.

Comment: Unfortunately that's how technology is; everything gets outdated quickly, including discussions about them. My answer was just thorough because I actually went through this exact situation several years ago and struggled with the issues that came up because of it. (And I'm still using that system today; man, do I need an upgrade. :-\)

Comment: I recently replaced my old Phenom II 965 BE  with a Ryzan 2700, because I zapped it while cleaning.  Of course this required a new board and DDR 4 modules as well. I stuck with Windows 7 because... (Windows 10, enough said). Well I soon discovered that I couldn't install Win 7 on the new hardware, because it doesn't support the board's USB 3.0 standard, so no keyboard / mouse functionality during install. Had to dig out an old PS\2 keyboard, create a special USB boot drive from the manufacturer, and so much more. Took 5 days to figure out. Best of all, no change in gaming performance lol.