# How can I elevate once and for all the monitoring software from my motherboard when logging with a normal account?

Tags: windows-7, uac, task-scheduler

I have recently [updated my Motherboard](https://superuser.com/questions/642246/how-to-replace-properly-motherboard-and-cpu-on-a-windows-7-machine). The new one (the make is Asus) provides a set of mostly monitoring/tuning software, e.g. to monitor the CPU temperature or stuff like that.

All is nice and well, except that every time I log as a normal user, without admin privileges, I receive 5 nagging pop ups asking for my attention and five times for the admin password. This is unnerving, and is not exactly appreciated by the wife, too.

It is exactly the same issue described [here in this forum](http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=2249093)  where a Task scheduler solution is proposed, the crux of which is, as far as I understand, to run the program as an admin.

Is this the best approach or is there something better to be done? Does it have any cons?

**UPDATE**

As requested, the programs in question are

- PowerControlHelp.exe
- AsusSetup
- U3BoostSvr.exe
- EPUHelp
- NetSvcHelpEntry
- AI Suite II

all signed by certified vendor ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.

Note that originally only the first five appear, then there is a further request by AI Suite II.

Comment: What programs have you set to be ran as an administrator?  Why is this tagged as `asus` when the brand of the motherboard isn't important.

Comment: @Ramhound it is something that happens with asus mb. I don't know if other motherboard makers use different approaches, but I have found that I am not the only asus user who encountered this issue. I have not specified the detail of which asus mb since I believe it not to be relevant. Please feel free to suggest improvement on the question as you see fit.

Comment: Address the first part of my comment I asked it for a specific reason.

Comment: @ramhound thanks for your feedback. Please be less terse, since it's not easy to understand in just few lines of comment. How can I check that info in a reliable way? Why is it relevant, or is it a riddle to be explained step by step?

Comment: I cannot explain the reasons I want to know what the 5 programs are in 500 words or less and I cannot answer this question without that information.

Comment: @Ramhound, since it is so important and so mysterious, please answer MY question: how can I check that info in a reliable way?

Comment: Running msconfig can provide that information. I assumed the program that are started after each UAC prompt was known.

Comment: I don't manually start ANY program, except for those 5 asus ones.

Comment: Based on your last comment it seems you do know which programs are causing the UAC prompt but your followup questions to my previous comment indicate you dont.  If you know which programs are causing the UAC prompt update your question with that information.  I will be unable to answer your question without that information.

Comment: @Ramhound the programs are the 5 monitoring tools from ASUS.

Comment: Yes I know. I want to know the specific name of the applications. I have an Asus board. I want to confirm I have the same programs. I will talk to you later in chat about this but i want to have the information already so I can do my research.

Comment: @Ramhound I have added the list of the programs in my last edit.

Comment: did you install these on a User or Administrator account?

Comment: @Ramhound they were installed during the process of updating the drivers of the new motherboard. So they were installed by an admin account.

Comment: Use the AI Suite cleaner then reinstall AI Suite with the "run as Administrator" I have an Asus motherboard and use the same programs

Comment: @Ramhound I will try to do that (by cleaner I assume you mean uninstaller? Could you please write that as an answer so that it can be voted and, eventually, accepted?

Comment: I will but the AI Cleaner isn't just the uninstaller the Rpublic of Gamers forum has more information it cleans up some left over stuff from AI Suite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

1. Open the Windows Task Scheduler application.
2. Click on the ASUS folder on the left side.
3. You'll see 5 tasks there: AI Suite, DigiPowerControl, iControlHelp, EasyUpdate etc..
4. In the Trigger column, its configured to trigger whenever "At log on of any user".

This is the problem. "Any user" includes those non-admin or normal users.  To fix this, you need to modify the trigger to run this program ONLY when you (as an admin) log in:

1. Select one of the Scheduled Task in the middle column
2. Click PROPERTIES in the right column.  A window will open up for that scheduler.
3. Click the TRIGGERS tab
4. Click the 'At log on of any user' trigger.
5. Click the EDIT button.
6. Change the setting from "Any user" to "Specific user" and select a user on that computer that has admin permissions.

This should fix your problem

Gary

Comment: This seems really promising. Will try it ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

a partial answer and a further ???
Same issue but with an error about a lost log file generated on an admin user acct also.
From a smart ASUS 3rd level tech - go to task scheduler and clear out the ASUS folder.
uninstall AI Suites
reboot
reinstall AI Suites - make sure there is no interruption of the installation.
When I did that 2 of the 5 went away.

HOWEVER 3 remain and I don't understand why because 2 r HELP programs and 1 is the U3Boost service - which any user should have access to.
any ideas out there?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the tasks' command line to be something like.

```
runas /user:ComputerName\AdministratorUser /savecred “C:\Path\To\Program.exe“
```

Essentially what this does is letting every user to run these programs in the context of 'AdministratorUser', kinda like setuid on Linux.

Answer (score -3):

You could turn off UAC.

Seriously. UAC isnt' for **everyone**.

Comment: How can I appreciate if it's for me? This is a bit surprising since in my experience a distinction between normal and admin/root users is present in most systems.

Comment: UAC != distinction between normal and admin users.  Distinction between normal and admin users has existed in Windows since the NT 4 days.

Comment: Yet they do seem related, since I am being asked the password for an admin user since my normal user isn't privileged enough. Now, back to my question: how can I appreciate if UAC is for me? If there is a relevant question/answer here on SU, please tell me.